# Is there a better way to get the created object?

Tags: python, django

I have this code and I want to store this created user and question in a variable in one line instead of doing it this weird way, is this even possible?:

```
    if UserProfile.objects.filter(discord_id=request.data['author_id']).exists():
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(discord_id=request.data['author_id'])
    else:
        x = UserProfile.objects.create(discord_id=request.data['author_id'], name=request.data['name'])
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(discord_id=request.data['author_id'])

    Question.objects.create(title=request.data['title'], author=profile, points=int(request.data['points']))
    question = Question.objects.filter(author=profile, title=request.data['title'])[0]
```

Comment: At the very least, the `get` after `create` is entirely superfluous, since `create` already returns the created object…

Comment: You would also rather do a `get` inside a `try..except UserProfile.DoesNotExist`, instead of doing an `if ...filter` followed by a `get`…

Comment: Oh, is it really? I had a problem with it and so I asked about it here, maybe I did something wrong, my bad then

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) for precisely this purpose.  So use:

```
obj, created = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(...)
```

> A convenience method for looking up an object with the given kwargs (may be empty if your model has defaults for all fields), creating one if necessary.
>
> Returns a tuple of (object, created), where object is the retrieved or created object and created is a boolean specifying whether a new object was created.
>
> This is meant to prevent duplicate objects from being created when requests are made in parallel, and as a shortcut to boilerplatish code.

Note also that [`Model.create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#create) will also return the created object, no need to query it again.

```
obj  = MyModel.create(...)
```

Comment: I mean, Im asking about this particular code "Question.objects.create(title=request.data['title'], author=profile, points=int(request.data['points']))
    question = Question.objects.filter(author=profile, title=request.data['title'])[0]"

Comment: @adrq wim's answer has everything you need. Change your if-else for the `get_or_create` function, and then just get the created object without your `.get`, just `question = Question.objects.create(...)`